# How to enable ramoops in android AOSP?

Tags: android-source

I'm having a AOSP codebase. I would like to enable ramoops in the system to debug system crashes. How can I enable ramoops in my AOSP ( Android Open Source Project ) code base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

Follow the instruction on

https://01.org/linuxgraphics/gfx-docs/drm/admin-guide/ramoops.html

**Summary**

1. Add "mem_address", "mem_size" & "mem_type" to the BOOTARGS variable in device.mk according to your hardware specific memory address.

   Eg. BOOT_ARGS += "mem=128M ramoops.mem_address=0x8000000 ramoops.ecc=1"

**For Additional reference:**
[Visit Google Documentation](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/android-3.18/Documentation/ramoops.txt)